# Some RDD actions failing with Java IllegalArgumentException

Tags: scala, apache-spark

For some reason when executing some (but not all) RDD actions on any kind of RDD a Java IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version x is thrown.  The strange thing is this only affects some actions (e.g. collect, take, first, etc) but NOT others (e.g. sample, takeOrdered, etc).  Any thoughts on what's wrong?

The version of Spark installed is 2.4.3 and I have upgraded JDK/JRE from 11 to 12 in case that was the issue.

```
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.4.3
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.11.12 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 12.0.1)
```

Previous version was throwing "Unsupported class file major version 55", now with the upgraded version it's the same but version 56 instead (so upgrade clearly successful, but not resolved issue).

Here is the output of a very simple RDD creation showing that the RDD is working for some actions:

```
val seqNum = sc.parallelize(0 to 1000)
seqNum: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Int] = ParallelCollectionRDD[37] at 
parallelize at <console>:24

seqNum.count
res30: Long = 1001

seqNum.sample(false, 0.01).foreach(println)
355
385
392
402
505
569
585
```

So the RDD is created and working as it should.  Here is what happens when using the exact same RDD with the take action though:

```
seqNum.take(10).foreach(println)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 56
  at org.apache.xbean.asm6.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:166)
  at org.apache.xbean.asm6.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:148)
  at org.apache.xbean.asm6.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:136)
  at org.apache.xbean.asm6.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:237)
  at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.getClassReader(ClosureCleaner.scala:49)
  at org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3$$anonfun$visitMethodInsn$2.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:517)
  at org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3$$anonfun$visitMethodInsn$2.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:500)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:733)
  at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$1$$anonfun$foreach$2.apply(HashMap.scala:134)
  at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$1$$anonfun$foreach$2.apply(HashMap.scala:134)
  at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:236)
  at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:40)
  at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$1.foreach(HashMap.scala:134)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:732)
  at org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3.visitMethodInsn(ClosureCleaner.scala:500)
  at org.apache.xbean.asm6.ClassReader.readCode(ClassReader.java:2175)
  at org.apache.xbean.asm6.ClassReader.readMethod(ClassReader.java:1238)
  at org.apache.xbean.asm6.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:631)
  at org.apache.xbean.asm6.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:355)
  at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean$14.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:307)
  at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean$14.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:306)
  at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
  at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:306)
  at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:162)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2326)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2100)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$take$1.apply(RDD.scala:1364)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.take(RDD.scala:1337)
  ... 49 elided</code>
```

Since the RDD is created properly and some actions work, I would have expected all actions to work - any idea what the issue is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like Spark 2.4 doesnt support Java 10/11 at the moment. Check the Jira link for the same
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-24417
To ensure that the job runs fine you may want to use JDK 8

Comment: Looking through that link it certainly does seem to be indicating that the error is a result of Spark not supporting the newer JREs so I guess that's the answer.  It's odd though as I had (obviously mis)interpreted the error as indicating an error in the Spark classes not being supported by the JRE, not the other way around...  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Just or the record; I installed JDK 8, updated the config and restarted Spark and indeed now everything works correctly.  <sigh>  Thanks for your help!